# Getting 401 unauthorized error when trying to get Uber diver profile information

Tags: uber-api

I have tried to get uber driver profile information using the following URL,

```
GET: https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/me
```

As a first step I have set scopes as follows in the authorization step and get the access token,

```
https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id={cliend_id}&response_type=code&response_type=code&scope=profile%20history%20request%20places
```

All working fine but when I try to get profile information, I got this error:

```
{
    "message": "This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: partner.accounts, partner.admin_accounts",
    "code":"unauthorized"
}
```

Comment: for accessing this information your login account don't have permission.

Comment: There are a few hits for this error on SO already. Be sure to let us know why those do not apply here...

Comment: The error message you get explains everything - in order to use  "GET : https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/me" endpoint you will need use one of the following scopes: partner.accounts, partner.admin_accounts.

Comment: Agreed, But the problem is how can I set those scopes ?

Answer (score 0):

Driver API is with limited [access](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/introduction). In order to access Driver API endpoints, you will need to apply for scope whitelisting - in your case it is partner.accounts. You can apply for access to Driver API here: https://developer.uber.com/products/drivers but just as a heads up access granting is currently very limited.

So after we review your access request - and you get access to the scope - please select it on your application [dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) - and when you authenticate your users - you will authenticate your users with this scope - and be able to access  "[GET /v1/partners/me](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-me-get)" endpoint.